# creating an emailable or printable document using an Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, document, .doc

Can anyone recommend a good source (either a tutorial or book?) on how to generate a .doc file from an Android App?
I am completely new to programming and don/t understand most of what I read as answers here, hence the need for a recommendation: I need to learn!
What I'm after is to be able to produce a document based on a standard template, containing a choice of standard paragraphs with user insertions, which can then be emailed, all from a smart phone or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you have a research task on your hands. If your requirements allow you to create an [Open Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) document then its possible to insert the user's paragraphs 'by hand'.

An [Open Office XML document is just a zip archive with XML files inside of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Unzip the template document using [java.util.zip](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) and locate the `word/document.xml` file inside. Insert the user's text using the DOM and persist the file.

Another approach would be to try to get [docx4j](http://joshuaborn.name/blog/0115/) integrated into your Android project. My guess is that this project reference many libraries that are not included with the Android SDK.

Good luck and hope this helps.